# Relative paths links in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with some email links. I would like to have a clickable link to download those files.

Having the two files (the excel and the email) in the same folder, the link file://test.eml or only test.eml does not open it, I need to use an absolute path. There would be a way to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The absolute path is a known value, but anyway, the file is not opened.

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\blanca.hernandez\Desktop\2012-05-24T09-41-11-0.00007.eml", "email")
```

It is funny, because something like

> file://C:\Users\blanca.hernandez\Desktop\2012-05-24T09-41-11-0.00007.eml

gives me a clickabe link to open the file, but if I want to do the same with other directory, as

> file://C:\repository\project\mail\archive\2012\5\24\11\2012-05-24T09-41-11-0.00007.eml

it is not possible to open. Are there some reasons for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Hyperlink(LinkLocation, FriendlyName")` function in conjunction with `Cell("filename")`

`Cell("filename")` returns the full file name of the file that contains the reference as
`C:\Full\Path\[FileName.xlsm]SheetName`
To get just the path use
`LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("*", SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"), "\", "*", LEN(CELL("filename")) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"\","")))))`

`Hyperlink(LinkLocation, FriendlyName")` creates a hyperlink

---

To link to the file `test.eml` the full formula is

```
=HYPERLINK(LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"\","*",LEN(CELL("filename"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"\","")))))&"test.eml","Link to File")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my question to explain better the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

that will give you the path to the workbook